# Hazelcast local entry listener on a Map

Tags: hazelcast, high-availability

I've been looking into using a local entry listener instead of a normal entry listener so that an event is only processes by a single listener.

I've found various posts on this topic such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58115233/prevent-hazelcast-to-register-evictionlistener-on-every-node?rq=1), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47274007/time-based-eviction-in-hazelcast?noredirect=1&lq=1), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47457364/hazelcast-execute-entryevictedlistener-only-once-per-cluster-in-client-mode?rq=1), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14721991/hazelcast-entry-listener-on-a-multinode-cluster) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55973293/hazelcast-ensure-entry-event-is-processed-by-a-single-handler). It seems that a local entry listener is indeed the way to go for handling an event only once in a multi node cluster.

However, I'm not sure how such a local entry listener would function under failure conditions. For instance, what happens to an evicted-event if the node which is the master for that entry is unavailable. Will the backup pick this up in time? Or could the event be missed due to hazelcast needing some time to figure out the master is down and a new master should be elected? Is this different between the older AP-system and the new CP-subsystem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've refrained from using a local entry listener. Instead we are now using the executorservice from hazelcast to schedule a named task. In this way, we can correctly respond to changes in the cluster. It does seem like hazelcast has a preferred member on which a task is executed, but that isn't an issue for us.

Answer (score 0):

From Hazelcast docs:

> Note that entries in distributed map are partitioned across the
>   cluster members; each member owns and manages the some portion of the
>   entries. Owned entries are called local entries. This listener will be
>   listening for the events of local entries. Let's say your cluster has
>   member1 and member2. On member2 you added a local listener and from
>   member1, you call {@code map.put(key2, value2)}. If the key2 is owned
>   by member2 then the local listener will be notified for the add/update
>   event. Also note that entries can migrate to other nodes for load
>   balancing and/or membership change.

The key part is: "Also note that entries can migrate to other nodes for load balancing and/or membership change.”

I guess that if an original partition owner fails, then some other node will become a new owner of those entries (or part of them, depending on cluster state after the repartitioning is done) and then it, the new owner, will run local entry listener.